Tree-sitter config.json
How do I get tree-sitter generate to create the bindings for the other bindings that are listed either https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/#language-bindings or https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/creating-parsers#command-generate? I am missing something. I have created manual bindings but I wanted to use the ones that have all the configuration which seems to have already been done.
tree-sitter generate and it only created rust and node, instead of C/C++, Go, Node, Python, Rust, Swift.

how to ask a good question:
how to ask
